# Submitting code created form data to POST

Tags: python, redirect, flask

I'm trying to submit form data to a route, similar to how a browser would, but am having trouble. I've simplified the code provided to the minimal I need to reproduce the problem. I'm probably not using a function I should or doing something else wrong but I can't find the answer in all the other posts I've searched. I don't want the data to be on the URL but rather accessible via request.form. I am using Python 2.7.9. I know the code shown below currently does NOT do what I want (it puts the formdata dictionary on the command line) and returns an endless loop because the formdata is never read. I understand this, I just did this to show that I'm trying to pass the formdata to the post function, I just don't know how to do it and also use redirect at the same time. If I'm reading the redirect documentation correctly it seems to say you can't do this. So is there some other function I can use that will pass the parameters to a URL and also provide the form data? I'm not using the parameters in the code below but my actual code has a similar function structure where I do use them. The main goal here is to have the same function (URL path) used when "choice" is or is not submitted via a form. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

```
from flask import Flask, redirect, url_for, request, render_template

web_server = Flask(__name__)

@web_server.route("/test_<param1>_<param2>",methods=['POST','GET'])
def test1(param1,param2):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        choice1 = 'No choice made yet'
        templateData = {'choice':choice1} 
        return render_template('form_page.html', **templateData)
    elif request.method == 'POST':
        if 'choice' in request.form:
            choice1 = request.form['choice']
            templateData = {'choice':choice1} 
            return render_template('form_page.html', **templateData)
        else:
            formdata = {'choice':'QQQ'}
            p1='AAA'
            p2='BBB'
            # the following line is NOT what I want to do. See question 
            return redirect(url_for('.test1',param1=p1,param2=p2,data=formdata),code=307)


# run server
if __name__ == "__main__":
    web_server.run(host='0.0.0.0',port=80,debug=True)
```

HTML:

```
Choice was {{choice}}<br><br>

<form method="post">
Make a choice:
<input type="text" name="choice"><br><br>
<input type="submit">
</form>

<form method="post">
Do anything else:
<input type="text" name="other"><br><br>
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: it is not really clear to me what you are trying to accomplish. can you rephrase the actual issue?

Comment: Thanks for reviewing and commenting. I'm trying to submit form data (something I can access in my program via request.form) from my code to a URL on my server. The form data should not be in the URL but rather submitted like a "submit" form would do. The posts I've come across don't quite do this. With regards to my code, If the line below my first code comment was fixed you would be able to run it and submit anything on the "Do anything else" html form and it would show you "QQQ" at the top of the web page. If this still isn't clear please let me know and I'll try to clarify. Thanks.

Comment: I just tested your code to see what is going on, and I think I now understand your issue. It lies within the redirect url_for statement. You try to pass arguments to be used inside the template, but instead it shows them in the url (and not in the template). As far as I know, this is not possible. url_for expects url arguments, it is not possible to use them in a template. As a solution you could use a render_template or use session to store any request.form post data.

Comment: I'm aware url_for won't submit a form like I want to do (I wasn't clear enough, my fault). I'm trying to learn if there is a way to submit form data with a POST request (besides having it on the URL) . I don't have to use redirect or url_for if there is another way as long as the data is available in the request.form. The session store data seems like a work around (although it's a good idea, I didn't think of it) but I'm not opposed to using it if I have to. Is there some other command I should be using to POST form data to a URL on that line instead of redirect or url_for?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by 'post form data to a url' ?

Comment: Sorry, I'm probably not using the correct terminology. I guess what I'm trying to say is I want to submit a POST command to (using my originally posted code as an example) http://www.mywebpage/test_<param1>_<param2>. Then, when my test1 function receives that submission in can access the form data in request.form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

lets see if this is what you mean, see quick and dirty code below. Have a close look at the request.args statement, that is where you can get the variables stored in the url.

```
from flask import Flask, redirect, url_for, request, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/',methods=['POST','GET'])
def test1():
if request.method == 'POST':
    if 'choice' in request.form:
        choice = request.form['choice']
        return render_template('test.html', choice = choice)
    else:
        choice = 'QQQ'
        p1 = 'AAA'
        p2 = 'BBB'
        return redirect(url_for('.test1',param1 = p1, param2 = p2, choice = choice))

choice = request.args.get("choice")
if choice == None:
    choice = 'No choice made yet'
return render_template('test.html',  choice = choice)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0',port=5000,debug=True)
```

Comment: Isn't request.args only used to access parameters in the URL? I'm trying to POST data that can be accessed from request.form.

Comment: see edit. Basically there is render template, where you can pass variables to the template. These variables you can get from request.form statement. Via url_for you can get the request.args. If both are not possible I would suggest using session. You could write to session in the post method part, and read from session in the get method. If these possibilities still do not cover your issues, I'm happy to hear from you.

Comment: Okay, I'll try your last suggestion when I get home tonight (at work now) and use session if I need to. Thanks for all your help and patience.